# Composing build schematics in angular

Tags: angular, ng-packagr, angular-schematics

I'd like to compose the ngpackagr schematic with my own.
Inside my custom rule I do something like:

`export function testScehma(_options: any): Rule {
  return chain([
    externalSchematic('@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr', 'build', _options),
    (tree: Tree, _context: SchematicContext) => {
      tree.create('testFile.txt', 'This is a Test!!!');
      return tree;
    }
  ]);
}`

Then I try to run: `ng my-test-lib build`.

I get the following error:

`Error: Package "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr" was found but does not support schematics.`

Where do I find the `ngpackagr` schematics to be able to extend it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schematics is used to manipulate files.

I don't think the build mechanism is built by schematic, but more with Webpack (and in the future - Bazel).

That's why I believe it says that `@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr` does not support schematics.

So I think that if you want to test it, try something like -

`externalSchematic('@schematics/angular', 'component', options)`

To experiment with how you can create custom components for example.

If you want to customize the build, I think that for now (unless I'm mistaken) you are bound to the configuration options that exist in the `angular.json` file.